# What can be purpose behind forward declared class without defining and using it anywhere in the project in C++?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, obs-studio

I was exploring famous [OBS Studio](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio) source code. That is using one [git sub-module](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) at
https://github.com/obsproject/libdshowcapture

In the file [source/capture-filter.hpp](https://github.com/obsproject/libdshowcapture/blob/master/source/capture-filter.hpp) there is a [forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) of a class which is nowhere defined and used in whole repo and whole OBS-Studio repo.

```
namespace DShow {

// some other declaration

// this class is nowhere defined and used
class CaptureSource;

//some other declaration and definitions
}
```

I checked carefully but did not find any definition nor usage of `CaptureSource` class. If I am right then what can be purpose of such declaration?

Comment: If you are right, than this is unused declaration, which serves no purpose.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux if there is no usage of `CaptureSource` class in the library, it's definition in the header is completely useless.

Comment: @SergeyA I missed that it was also unused. I understood it to simply be undefined.

Comment: It was most likely useful seven years ago, when that code was written, but the surrounding code has changed since then. Since it's not an error to never use a forward-declared class, it's very easy to leave behind.

Comment: this is very famous project I dont think it would be really a unused class

Comment: @AlokSinghMahor _"famous project"_ really does not guarantee good quality of the code ;-)

Comment: The only use case I'm aware of for using a forward declaration that is not defined is as a discriminator tag in a template.  Like `using Address_type = NamedType<std::string, struct Address_tag>;` where the *in situ* `struct Address_tag` is a forward declaration.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I have mentioned in question that its not defined nor used anywhere in the whole project.

Comment: Maybe file an issue on the github page to see why it still exists. I did verify from a search that it was never used. Edit: I see the issue tab does not exist. I assume there is some way to notify the developers on this project.

Comment: i don't quite understand the question. If you know that it isnt used anywhere, then it isnt used anywhere, aka it has no purpose

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I am assuming that its a famous high quality project so I dont think its really a unused class. May be there would be some purpose that I am trying to find out.

Comment: I think we understood that now. Please consider that this project is maybe not as famous as you think, and even if it was having such an artifact as leftover from past refactoring can happen even in the most clean projects

Comment: @AlokSinghMahor All projects of a non-trivial size and age contain code that no longer serves any purpose. They also contain misleading comments and code that is not as good as it could be. And bugs.

Comment: ^^ this and if you have to choose what to fix then you usually choose bugs ;)